# Why Won't My Variables Work?

Tags: java, variables

I'm trying to make a bank, I'm making a Scanner option thing so if you press 1 You can withdraw money if you press 2 You will add money and 3 for getting off the bank. But when I press 2 or 3 it doesn't do anything, I tried else if but then I get loads more errors and I don't know the difference.

------NOTE------
I tried un nesting (if thats a phrase) them but I get a syntax error on else near the button (I have marked where) So Im not sure how to fix that

```
import java.util.Scanner;




public class Bank {




    public static void main (String [] args) {
     System.out.println("Welcome To Harry's Bank");


    //Pin System
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Bank Pin.");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
        int number;
        int password = 7123;
        int amount = 4000;

        number = userInput.nextInt();

        if (number == password) {
        System.out.println("Pin Accepted");
        System.out.println("You Have Now Entered Harry's Bank!");
        System.out.println("Press The Number Of The Option You Would Like.");
        System.out.println("1.Withdraw Money.");
        System.out.println("2.Put In Money");
        System.out.println("3.Exit Bank");
        Scanner Options = new Scanner (System.in);
        int option;
        option = userInput.nextInt();

        if (option == 1) {
        //Withdraw Money System
        System.out.println("You Have £4000");
        System.out.println("How Much Would You Like To Take Out?");
        Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numbere;


        numbere = userInput.nextInt();
        if (numbere < 4000) {

        int money = amount - numbere;
            System.out.println("You Have Now £" + money);
            System.out.println("Thank You For Banking At Harry's Bank!");
            System.out.println("Please Come Again!");
          }else{
                System.out.println("You Do Not Have Enough Money!"); 
          }
        }


        else if (option == 2) {
            //AddMoney System
            Scanner AddMoney = new Scanner (System.in);
            int AddMoney1;
            AddMoney1 = userInput.nextInt();
            int NewMoney = (amount + AddMoney1);
            System.out.println("How Much Would You Like To Enter?");
            System.out.println("You Now Have " + NewMoney + "!");
            System.out.println("Thank You For Using Harry's Bank!");




        }
        else if (option == 3) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Next Time Only Press 1,2 or 3!");
        }
         //error Here For Else "Syntax error on token "else", { expected"
        }else{
                System.out.println("Pin Declined!");

          }



            }








        }
```

Comment: Proper code indentation would have shown the solution immediately :)

Answer (score 8):

Your brackets are off. You have

```
if(option ==1)
{
     if(option == 2)
     {
         //stuff
     }

     if(option == 3)
     {
         //stuff
     }
}
```

move those ifs out side the first

Answer (score 1):

Because 3rd and 4th if statement are out of reach. If you do not press 1, they will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

You have your if statements nested inside the if for "option == 1" so you can't reach options 2 or 3, this should be a chain of else if's